# ASP MVC ConfirmEmailAsync not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I register a user, receive a token via email which looks like this:

`Please confirm your account by clicking <a href="http://localhost:11080/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=51d95921-c240-4025-ac38-7dfc08a1012f&code=Jc58CjzNK6mkeaFT0U7iO68aKP4OrQtYWY9AWCkJtWpnc948kiR%2Bxq9PnptItf1kpKjgi0OyZdguBwCvePOQ%2Bf5P3IPTZwdVA%2FEJ%2F6A9iscTKjDcR2Q9bJH%2FH76S5h1W0lsSSLxfad2Bjrr4H%2BySgP70uktmZIUkhQXnIJN1%2BqBuJ9EfWeuytOfbv1i%2FkNtV">here</a>`

I click the link and I can see that the `ConfirmEmail` method in `AccountController` fires:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
    {
        if (userId == null || code == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
        return View(result.Succeeded ? "ConfirmEmail" : "Error");
    }
```

And that `result.Succeeded` is `true`.

Everything appears fine, but when trying to log in after completing this process I get taken to the page telling me my account is locked

> Locked out.
>
> This account has been locked out, please try again later.

What couldI be doing wrong? Do I need to manually change the lockout flag in the db? If so, what is the point of the `ConfirmEmailAsync` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ConfirmEmailAsync` just sets the `EmailConfirmed` on the user account record to true. From [UserManager](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/87bbff65867710b5a49265fdf09de4a6d539ac8d/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs#L1403) (edited for brevity):

```
public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> ConfirmEmailAsync(TUser user, string token)
{
    ...
    var store = GetEmailStore();
    ...
    await store.SetEmailConfirmedAsync(user, true, CancellationToken);
    return await UpdateUserAsync(user);
}
```

Where `GetEmailStore` returns the `IUserEmailStore` (which is implemented by `UserStore` by default), which [sets the flag](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/b355f59a013f263e7d41dbeca518ea96866640f0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores/UserStoreBase.cs#L490):

```
public virtual Task SetEmailConfirmedAsync(TUser user, bool confirmed, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    ...
    user.EmailConfirmed = confirmed;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

The error you're getting indicated that the `LockoutEnabled` flag on the user account is true. You can set this to false by calling the `SetLockoutEnabledAsync` method on the `UserManager`.

There is also a `SupportsUserLockout` flag on the `UserManager` which unlocks accounts by default on creation. In order to set this you will need to create your own `UserManager` and override this flag to false.

Comment: calling `SetLockoutEnabledAsync(userId, false)` did it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At first, I had challenges getting these to work and after a series of research no success. Finally, I got the root of the problem(s) and fixed them thus sharing my experience.  Follow the following process and I am sure it will help.

Step 1
Goto Startup.cs and remove the code below if you have it initialised;

```
services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
{
     options.LowercaseUrls = true;
     //options.LowercaseQueryStrings = true; //(comment or remove this line)
});
```

Step 2 For GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync() / ConfirmEmailAsync()
2a. On registering new user for token generation go as thus;

```
var originalCode = await userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
var code = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(originalCode);
var confirmationLink = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account",
                                      new { userId = user.Id, token = code }, Request.Scheme);
```

2b. On receiving confrimationLink for email confirmation, go as thus

```
var originalCode = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(token);
var result = await userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, originalCode);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    return View(); //this returns login page if successful
}
```

3. For `GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync()` and `ResetPasswordAsync()`

   a.

   ```
    var originalCode = await userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
    var code = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(originalCode);
    var passwordResetLink = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account",
                            new { email = model.Email, token = code }, Request.Scheme);
   ```

   b.

   ```
    var orginalCode = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(model.Token);
    var result = await userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, orginalCode, model.Password);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return View("ResetPasswordConfirmation");
    }
   ```